# Largest Possible Cow

Tags: katamari-damacy

I recently started playing the original Katamari Damacy, and one level that frustrates me to no end is "Make Tauros" (Also Make Ursa Major, but one constellation at a time).  The king is SO picky about how big your cow is, yet he will immediately take anything you roll up that looks even slightly like a cow.

Where is the biggest possible cow, and how can I get to it in this level?

Answer (score 3):

That would be the **Holy Cow in Seagull Park**:

[image: Holy Cow]

Here's a video on how to approach: